# Can't put column name into GetString

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand, getstring

I have got this code:

```
public void chyt_data()
    {
        try
        {


            SqlCommand novyprikaz = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM zajezd WHERE akce=" + currentrowstring, spojeni);
            spojeni.Open();
            SqlDataReader precti = novyprikaz.ExecuteReader();

            if (precti.Read())
            {

                zakce.Text = precti.GetString(0);
                zname.Text = precti.GetString(2);

         }

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Chybové hlášení2: " + ex.Message.ToString());
     }

     spojeni.Close();
   }
```

if i insert column name in it it like this:

```
    zakce.Text = precti.GetString("akce");
```

it wouldn't work.

May someone please help me solve this out ?
Thank you so much

it gives two errors:

1:Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)' has some invalid arguments

2: Error    2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

Comment: You can't do that. `SqlDataReader.GetString()` accepts only parameter with `int` type (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much, so if the value is char, I should use GetChar right?

Comment: @MarekŠíp nope; GetChar is not supported on SqlDataReader - it doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the [GetOrdinal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getordinal.aspx) function

```
zakce.Text = precti.GetString(precti.GetOrdinal("akce"));
zname.Text = precti.GetString(precti.GetOrdinal("name"));
```

Answer (score 2):

For things like:

```
zakce.Text = precti.GetString("akce");
```

there are several options:

```
zakce.Text = (string)precti["akce"];
```

or if you aren't *sure* that it is a `string`:

```
zakce.Text = Convert.ToString(precti["akce"]);
```

or:

```
int idx = precti.GetOrdinal("akce");
zakce.Text = precti.GetString(idx);
```

Answer (score 1):

`SqlDataReader.GetString()` method accepts only parameter with `int` type. So you have to pass column number instead of column name to get the value.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
  if (precti.Read())
        {

            zakce.Text = precti[0].ToString();
            zname.Text = precti[2].ToString();

        }
```